# How to create a MemoryStream packet and extract relevant data from NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, memorystream, networkstream

I've created packetReader & packetBuilder for passing and receiving packets that contain string message (using TcpClient and TcpListener in the server)

and I'm trying to do the same with byte[].

Here is how the message packet is built : [image: message packet]

**How to implement the same `WriteCanvasStrokes()` and `ReadCanvasStrokes()` ?**

Here is how I send to server:

```
TcpClient _client;

public void SendMessageToServer(string message)
    {
        var messagePacket = new PacketBuilder();
        messagePacket.WriteOpCode(5);
        messagePacket.WriteMessage(message);
        _client.Client.Send(messagePacket.GetPacketBytes());
    }


 public void SendCanvasStrokesToServer(MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        var strokesPacket = new PacketBuilder();
        strokesPacket.WriteOpCode(7);
        strokesPacket.WriteCanvasStrokes(memoryStream.GetBuffer());
        _client.Client.Send(strokesPacket.GetPacketBytes());
    }
```

PacketBuilder :

```
 public class PacketBuilder
    {
        MemoryStream _ms;
        public PacketBuilder()
        {
            _ms = new MemoryStream();
        }
        public void WriteOpCode(byte opcode)
        {
            _ms.WriteByte(opcode);
        }
        public void WriteMessage(string msg)
        {
            var msgLength = msg.Length;
            _ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(msgLength));
            _ms.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg));
        }
        public void WriteCanvasStrokes(byte[] strokes)
        {
            _ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(strokes.Length));
            _ms.Write(strokes);
        }
        public Byte[] GetPacketBytes()
        {
            return _ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

PacketReader :

```
  public class PacketReader : BinaryReader
    {
        private NetworkStream _ns;
        public PacketReader(NetworkStream ns) : base(ns)
        {
            _ns = ns;
        }
        public string ReadMessage()
        {
            byte[] msgBuffer;
            var length = ReadInt32();
            msgBuffer = new byte[length];
            _ns.Read(msgBuffer, 0, length);

            var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msgBuffer);
            return msg;
        }
        public byte[] ReadCanvasStrokes()
        {
            byte[] strokesBuffer;
            var length = ReadInt32();
            strokesBuffer = new byte[length];
            _ns.Read(strokesBuffer, 0, length);

            return strokesBuffer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like `ReadCanvasStrokes` already returns the "message" part of a message, can you give an example of it going wrong? Btw reading from a networkstream with a single Read call is unreliable, it can read fewer bytes than requested which is why it returns the actual number of bytes read.

Comment: @harold Is WriteCanvasStrokes() implemented same as WriteMessage() ?

Comment: Yep, you need loops for filling your buffers until you've received all the bytes you expected. Even for reading the four bytes that make up the length, you've no guarantee they'll all be received in a single call to `Read`.

Comment: Also, `GetBuffer` is almost always the wrong method to call on `MemoryStream` - you should generally use `ToArray`, or, better here, `CopyTo`. Don't get in the business of manually handling buffers when copying data between streams.